# Can VSCode start a selection that will automatically extend with cursor movement?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keymapping

I'm evaluating VSCode as a replacement for Atom (which replaced SlickEdit), but I can't determine if it will support the selection behavior I was able to achieve with Atom and Slick.  I have my cursor movement keys redefined, which is generally incompatible with holding down "shift" and extending the selection via standard cursor movement keys.  Does VSCode support the notion of starting (or "anchoring") a selection with a key-mapping of my choice (say, Ctrl-M), then allowing the selection to move and extend as I navigate around with my other (redefined) cursor movement keys?

Comment: The closest I know of: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_shrinkexpand-selection

Comment: @VonC Yes, I had seen that feature too, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.  It seems like it would be necessary to code an extension in order to get that capability (which I know nothing about, not yet anyway), and installing an external plugin was how I got it to work within Atom.  Luckily, some Atom contributor already did that work, and I was hoping that someone in VSCode-land would have beat me to it.  It's not likely that I'll find the time to do this myself, so switching to VSCode from Atom might not be an option...

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution is in the Insiders' Build and so maybe v1.46.

You can now *anchor* a selection start point and then later with a keybinding select everything between the cursor and that anchor point.  The commands are:

`Set Selection Anchor` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

`Select From Anchor to Cursor` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

`Go to Selection Anchor`

See [Anchor selections testing](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98087)

Not exactly what you wanted but a big step in the right direction.